# How to write into Heroku logs from application?

Tags: logging, heroku

I'm debugging an application and I would love to print things in the log to debug better, but I haven't found how in the [blog post on logging on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/logging-on-heroku) works.

I would love to store things so I check the content back when doing a `$ heroku logs`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set up [logplex](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logplex).

you can create a log drain on behalf of the app and receive the log data. more details here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/accessing-app-logs